# Multiple file selection

Tags: javascript, html, lotus-domino, filedrop.js

I'm playing with [FileDrop](http://filedropjs.org/) library, to allow users to upload multiple files "one-shot" with IE11.
As documented, setting this property

```
zone.multiple(true);
```

is possible to select multiple files to be uploaded.

I noticed this strange behaviour.

If I download the [sample package](http://github.com/ProgerXP/FileDrop/archive/master.zip), setting the multiple property into `filedrop.js` and run it locally (open `basic.html` file whith IE) everything works fine.

If I put the same HTML code into an HTML form in Lotus Domino, multiple selection doesn't work.

I repeat, it only happens with IE, using other browser everything is ok.

Which could be the problem? Any workaround to make it works?

UPDATE:

Note that [this page](http://filedropjs.org/#aborting), with IE, works fine, and multiple selection is allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to add

```
<meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge,chrome=1\">
```

into `<head>` section of the form